How to use Magento's built-in Cookie Restriction Mode with PWA Studio?
I'm new on PWA Studio and I'm trying to enable the Cookie Restrition Mode.
I followed this documentation: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/stores/compliance-cookie-restriction-mode.html
But it doesn't seem to work. I know that when it comes to PWA things are different from Luma, but I couldn't find the right way to do that yet.
I'd like to know if this is possible to be done or if I should work other tool to add this cookies policy feature?

I always assumed that PWA Studio does not use Cookies, is it?
